# SQLAlchemy: Method to retrieve all rows where a column value is substring of another string

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I am using SQLAlchemy to connect to an SQLite database which contains my words

I want to retrieve all the rows in which the value of column 'token' is a substring of a string 'myToken'

Here's how the class looks:

```
class Word(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    token = Column(String)
```

The example result should be like:

```
myToken = "alpha"

result = ["lph", "alp",]
```

I've tried using various methods
Some of them include:

```py
res = session.query(Word).where(str(Word.token) in myToken).first()
```

Result: None

```py
res = session.query(Word).filter(myToken.contains(str(Word.token))).first()
```

Result: None

```py
res = session.query(Word).where(Word.token.like(myToken)).first()
```

Result: None

```py
res = session.query(Word).filter(or_(
      Word.token.like('%' + myToken),
      Word.token.like(myToken + '%'),
      Word.token == myToken,
)).first()
```

Result: None